# C# Function Chaining

Tags: c#, chaining

Why do i receive error in the following declaration ?

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int>().AddRange(new int[]{1,2,3,45});
```

Error :Can not convert type void to List ?

Comment: Because AddRange does not return a List<T>.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) function does not return a value. You might need to perform this in two steps:

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int>();
intrs.AddRange(new int[]{1,2,3,45});
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also use a collection initializer (assuming C# 3.0+).

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 45 };
```

Edit by 280Z28: This works for anything with an `Add` method. The constructor parenthesis are optional - if you want to pass thing to a constructor such as the capacity, you can do so with `List<int>(capacity)` instead of just `List<int>` written above.

Here's an MSDN reference for details on the [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "a", "first" },
        { "b", "second" }
    };
```

Comment: Yes I am using C# 3.0.Thanks.

Comment: It is syntactic sugar - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Because [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) modifies the specified list instead of returning a new list with the added items. To indicate this, it returns `void`.

Try this:

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int>();
intrs.AddRange(new int[]{1,2,3,45});
```

If you want to create a new list without modifying the original list, you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int>();
List<int> newIntrs = intrs.Union(new int[]{1,2,3,45}).ToList();
// intrs is unchanged
```

Answer (score 5):

AddRange does not return the list it has added items to (unlike StringBuilder). You need to do something like this:

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int>();
intrs.AddRange(new int[]{1,2,3,45});
```

Answer (score 2):

AddRange() is declared as:

```
public void AddRange(object[]);
```

It does not return the list.

Answer (score 1):

By the way in C# 3.x (not sure about 2.0) you can do either of

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int>{1,2,3,45};
List<int> intrs = new []{1,2,3,45}.ToList(); // with Linq extensions
```

Besides other answers, you can add your own extension method that will add range and return list (not that it's a good practice).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you had already declared intrs, you could have done it with parentheses:

```
(intrs = new List<int>()).AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 45 });
```

However, I like the initialization syntax better.

Answer (score 0):

Although others have already mentioned that AddRange does not return a value, based on the samples given for alternatives it should also be remembered that the constructor of List will take an IEnumerable of T as well in addition to the code previously mentioned that is .NET 3.5+

For example:

```
List<int> intrs = new List<int>(new int[]{2,3,5,7});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another way.

```
List<int> intrs =  new List<int>
                        {
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            45
                        };
```

Comment: Yes, I know this wasn't entirely relevant to method chaining.